# Function template specialization with const ref arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-specialization, function-templates

The following code [compiles fine](http://cpp.sh/4vqwd).

```
#include <iostream>

struct rgb8{
    uint8_t r() const {return 0;};
};


template<typename L, typename P>
L pixelToLevel(P p) {
    return static_cast<L>(p);
}

template<>
uint8_t pixelToLevel<uint8_t, rgb8>(rgb8 p) {  //       <---------- line X
    return pixelToLevel<uint8_t, uint8_t>(p.r());
}


int main()
{
  pixelToLevel<uint8_t>(rgb8());
  return 0;
}
```

But if in line X I change `rgb8 p` to `const rgb8& p`, it fails to compile.

(The exact compiler error generated depends on whether or not the explicit template argument `rgb8` is also changed to `const rgb8&`.)

How can I get it to compile if I want to pass `p` by reference rather than by value on line X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the template parameter in the declaration of specialization, and template argument when calling it too. Otherwise the primary template would be called instead. e.g.

```
template<>
uint8_t pixelToLevel<uint8_t, const rgb8&>(const rgb8& p) {  //       <---------- line X
    return pixelToLevel<uint8_t, uint8_t>(p.r());
}
```

then

```
pixelToLevel<uint8_t, const rgb8&>(rgb8());
```

[LIVE](http://cpp.sh/6kjgr)

---

**EDIT**

Given `pixelToLevel<uint8_t>(rgb8());`, template argument deduction is performed with primary template and `P` is deduced as `rgb8` (it won't be deduced as `const rgb8&` with current primary template's parameter declaration), then the specialization version won't be called.

You can apply overloading instead of template specialization. e.g.

```
template<typename L, typename P>
L pixelToLevel(P p) {
    return static_cast<L>(p);
}

template<typename L>
L pixelToLevel(const rgb8& p) {  //       <---------- line X
    return pixelToLevel<L, uint8_t>(p.r());
}
```

Then `pixelToLevel<uint8_t>(rgb8());` would select the 2nd overload.

[LIVE](http://cpp.sh/2q6io)

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution to @songyuanyao's would be

```
template<typename L, typename P>
L pixelToLevel(const P& p) {
    return static_cast<L>(p);
}
```